# Better and cheaper alternative to godaddy?

Tags: domains

Could you recommend cheaper but still reliable domain registrar for .com and .co.uk? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are tons of them, but Lifehacker published an article with the "[5 Best Domain Name Registars](http://lifehacker.com/5683682/five-best-domain-name-registrars)" that can be useful.

The candidates: Namecheap, Name, 1&1, Go Daddy and Gandi.

Comment: That seems oriented towards home use and cheapness, not really the key features for a serious-use domain.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.name.com - a good registrar

Since the .com price was raised 2 times now, probably it's hard to find a < $10 price for .com. It seems they will increase .com every year (as it is the most used) from now on.

Answer (score 0):

[Internet.bs](http://internet.bs/) is my current favorite to replace GoDaddy, with [moniker.com](http://moniker.com/) my second-choice (in both instances, I'm less than a month into moving a domain there from GoDaddy).  Moniker limits the number of nameservers to 6 and does not seem to have a way to do IPv6 glue records for the nameservers (I asked and it's been a week with no actual answer, just a note that my question was being escalated); Internet.bs has 13 spots for nameservers (I haven't asked if they could do more) and can do IPv6 glue records.